# grep contain between 2 regex in a same line

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep

I have a file like this :

```
1. Dé 33 2. iis ET 3. 56 RRE- 4. etc...
```

And i would like to get :

```
1. Dé 33
2. iis ET
3. 56 RRE-
4. etc...
```

I thought using grep or sed. I tried many unsuccessful commands. The closest command I found is :

```
cat myfile | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,2\}\. '
```

that leads to :

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
```

So, basically what I need is a grep function that select things between two regex (eg I want everything between a number foollowed by a point)

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo " 1. Dé 33 2. iis ET 3. 56 RRE- 4. etc..." | sed 's/[0-9]\+\./\n&/g'

1. Dé 33 
2. iis ET 
3. 56 RRE- 
4. etc...
```

**explanation:**

*in search pattern*
[0-9]\+ searches for numbers, at list one digit must be present, for example [0-9]* can find digits but also empty string.
\. dot must in this case be backslashed since . in regexes represents anychar

*in replacement pattern*
\n will put newline character,
& will put same search pattern, in other words nothing changed except \n inserted before condition,
g at the end will make replace to all found search patterns

Idea in short terms is to put newline \n char before numbers ending with dot

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%3==0?RS:FS)}' file
1. De 33
2. iis ET
3. 56 RRE-
4. etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports `-P` then you could use the below grep command.

```
$ grep -oP '.*?(?=\s\d+\.|$)' file
1. Dé 33
2. iis ET
3. 56 RRE-
4. etc...
```

`.*?(?=\s\d+\.|$)` Non-greedy match of zero or more characters which must be followed [by a space again followed by one or more digits , further followed by a dot] **or** by  end of the line anchor `$`.